# Extract time zone identifier from DateTime instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a way to extract friendly zone identifier (like CET, GMT or UTC) from a DateTime instance.

A few of my failed attempts:

```
>> DateTime.current.zone
=> "+00:00" # Not what I want

>> Time.current.zone
=> "UTC"
>> DateTime.current.to_time.zone
=> "CET" # Uses system time instead of the one set in Rails config
```

I also managed to find that if you cast DateTime instance to a specific zone, `DateTime#zone` returns the abbreviation I'm looking for, but that doesn't work for uncast instance:

```
>> DateTime.current.in_time_zone('America/Los_Angeles').zone
=> "PDT"
>> DateTime.current.zone
=> "+00:00
```

Comment: `Time.current.zone` is not what you are looking for?

Comment: Eventually `Time.zone` which "Returns the TimeZone for the current request. [...] If `Time.zone` has not been set [...], returns the TimeZone specified in `config.time_zone`. " (source: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone)

Comment: That's what I settled for now, but imagine that you have a DateTime instance cast to some specific time zone – you can't then use it Time.current.zone, as it'd not be the time zone the DateTime instance is cast to. But your reply made me I find a partial solution to my problem, thanks. ;)

Comment: `Time.now.zone` ?

Answer (score 1):

Another one to try: `Time.now.zone`

Other time related goodies:

- [Rails api docs for Time](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html)
- [Thoughtbot timezone article](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/its-about-time-zones)